# Serial Communication - byte stream

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am attempting to serially communicate with a XM tuner.  The tuner requires that a series of bytes be sent from the comport to control the tuner, an example of the command stream would be as follows: "B8,4D,18,30,20,B8".  Initially, I attempted to send the command as a string (below), which did not work.

```
 _Comport.Write("B8,4D,18,30,20,B8");
```

I also attempted to convert the command to a byte array, however this also was not effective.

```
 System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
 Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes("B8,4D,18,30,20,B8");               
 _Comport.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
```

The comport is open and receives messages from the tuner; however I am at a loss as to how to transmit the stream of bytes to the tuner.  Could someone kindly steer me as to how I need to communicate appropriately with the tuner?

Comment: You're sending that data as strings, and when you use `.GetBytes`, you're just getting the bytes of the string representation of what you have in quotes.  You need to send an actual array of bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to literally send those as bytes, not an ASCII byte representation, you would do something like this:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 0xB8, 0x4D, 0x18, 0x30, 0x20, 0xB8 };
_Comport.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

The `0x` in front of the numbers indicates to the compiler that they are hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: Does C# actually have a byte literal?  According to this post, it doesn't:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/43059/362536  Is that post wrong?

Comment: That post is not wrong but refers to the fact that you can't explicitly request a byte literal in the language. The values here are actually int literals that are converted at compile-time to bytes, due to the element type of the array.

Comment: @InternalServerError, Ah, that makes sense!   Thanks for that clarification.  All this time, I've been doing arrays with each element cast...